# What does slash dot refer to in a file path?

Tags: windows, git, gruntjs, filepath, slash

I'm trying to install a `grunt` template on my computer but I'm having issues. I realized that perhaps something different is happening because of the [path given by the Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding), which is

```
%USERPROFILE%\.grunt-init\
```

What does that `.` mean before `grunt-init`?

I've tried to do the whole import manually but it also isn't working

```
 git clone https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile.git "C:\Users\Imray\AppData\Roaming\npm\gru
nt-init\"
```

I get a message:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\Imray\AppData\Roaming\npm\.grunt-init"'.: Invalid argument
```

Does it have to do with this `/.`? What does it mean?

Comment: `/.foo` refers to a file or folder named `.foo`. i don't think the `.` has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Telling us it "isn't working" does no good unless you tell us *how* it isn't working. Please update your question with that information. If you're seeing error messages, please copy-and-paste them verbatim into your question.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe post a new question where you state the actual thing you are trying to do and what problem you are having

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` (that's a backslash, not a slash) is a directory delimiter. The `.` is simply part of the directory name.

`.grunt-init` and `grunt-init` are two distinct names, both perfectly valid.

On Unix-like systems, file and directory names starting with `.` are hidden by default, which is why you'll often see such names for things like configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is part of a directory name. Filenames can contain `.` . The `\` is a separator between directory names.

Typically, files or directories starting with `.` are considered "hidden" and/or used for storing metadata. In particular, shell wildcard expansion skips over files that start with `.`.

For example if you wrote `ls -d *` then it would not show any files or directories beginning with `.`  (including `.` and `..`, the current and parent directories).

Answer (score 0):

Linux hides files and directories whose names begin with dot, unless you use the a (for "all") option when listing directory contents.  If this convention is not followed on Windows, your example is probably just a carryover.

It may well be something behind the scenes (later) expects that name to match exactly.  While I like things, installers, for example, to just do what I said, I realize that keeping default value is the most tested path.

Answer (score 0):

Directories starting with a dot are invisible by default on xNIX systems. Typically used for configurations files and similar in a users home directory.

Answer (score 0):

`\` before `"` has a special meaning on windows, the error is because windows won't let you create a file containing `"` as part of its name.